# Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter'

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to install OpenSSH from https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server but on the 3rd step while running

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1 -Confirm:$false
```

I'm getting the error:

> C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1 : Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type
>   'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter 'Confirm'.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [FixHostFilePermissions.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,FixHostFilePermissions.ps1

Comment: Remove `-Confirm:$false` from the command and manually answer any prompts you receive.

Comment: Thanks  for the help, i'm not getting the error anymore.

Comment: @JamesC. nice but that doesnt really help. what if we need this to be automated and not have any prompts?

Comment: In this question `Confirm` is a Switch Parameter, these are `$false` by default and become `$true` when used. Using a Switch param (making it true) then setting it to false is no different than not including it at all.